# Service Worker prevents Nginx to match location

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, create-react-app

With Nginx I'm serving a CMS application on `/admin` and a React app with React Router on `/`.

If I check `/admin` I can see the CMS. But if I go to `/` (where I see the app) and then I go back to `/admin` I get the `404` page of the app. After that it's impossible to see the CMS.

The only way to see the CMS again is to clean browser history and go to `/admin` first.

If I use `curl` on terminal though I cannot replicate the issue.

#### My guess

Create-React-App service worker is preventing other locations once downloaded

#### Nginx config

```
server {
    # ...some code

    root /home/myuser/app/build;

    location ~ ^/admin(/.*|$) {
        alias /home/myuser/admin/public$1;
        # ...some code
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.html?$ {
        expires 1d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is related to [Configuring the Proxy Manually](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuring-the-proxy-manually) on Create React App **PWA**

Answer (score 0):

may be try this code

```
server {
    # ...some code

    root /home/myuser/app/build;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        alias /home/myuser/admin/public$1;
        # ...some code
    }

    ~ \.html?$ {
        expires 1d;
    }
}
```

Comment: `location ~ ^/admin(/.*|$)` is mandatory to work with [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri-or-subdirectory). I cannot change it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up unregistering the Service Worker as per [Dan's comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2715#issuecomment-312666604).

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';

// ...

unregister();
```

Once done Nginx configuration is honoured.